# Initialize abstract class reference from class construction in one line

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

I am wondering how we would asign a class reference of a child class to an abstract class reference in one line.

I know this works:

```
MyClass c;
MyAbstractClass &b = c;
```

But I really cannot figure out how it could work to do this in one line, something like:

```
MyAbstractClass &b = MyClass();
```

Is this even possible in C++ with a reference? I know it works with pointers etc. (so should work with reference as well?) and also in other languages like Java.

Comment: You can't take a non-const (lvalue) reference to a temporary (prvalue).

Comment: references are just references. The objects has to be stored somewhere

Comment: To build on @cigien's comment, temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the expression. So the reference will not point to a valid object.

Comment: @cigien can we use `MyAbstractClasss &&b = MyClass();`?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `MyClass b;`, and dispense with the reference? What's the larger problem you're trying to solve by using the reference?

Comment: @Harry Technically, yes, but `b` is dangling, so you can't really use it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm MyAbstractClass should be an abstract "Sensor" that has some functions but that can be from different manufacturers (e.g. MyClass1 or MyClass2). This specific Manufacturer should be set at the beginning but passed that schould only be handled as an abstract "Sensor". Please point me to a better pattern, that might better solve this

Comment: How do you choose between the different sensors? Is it done at compile time (e.g. a macro or enum), or at runtime?

Comment: lets say you have a function `foo( MyAbstractClass& f)` then you can simply write `MyClass c; foo(c);`. Its not clear why you want to sequeze those two lines into one

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm at compile time